# (C++) ReadProcessMemory - Problems with reading one byte

Tags: c++, memory, process

The problem I'm having is in the 'Address value:' section.
Basically, if I don't put byteSize to 4 (int), it will cout -858993409 as the address value. The 4 bytes at 0x242E1698 are FF 00 00 00. If I put byteSize as 4, it will output 255 (as I want it to). 
Is there any way to output 255 by only reading one byte?

```
int byteSize = 1;       
if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)0x242E1698, (void *)&healthVar, byteSize, NULL))
    cout << "Failed to read " << windowName << "'s memory!\n\n";
else
{
    cout << "Address value: " << healthVar << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: How is `healthVar` defined?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish? I don't think it's "output 255 by reading one byte"

Answer (score 0):

If you read only one byte, you need to read it into a one-byte integer:

```
uint8_t healthVar;
```

Then once you read your value (255) into there, you can print it this way:

```
cout << unsigned(healthVar) << endl;
```

Note you cannot simply print `healthVar` because in C++ a one-byte integer will be printed as a character instead.